# MySQL Table: Display every row with criteria met

Tags: php, mysql

How does one go about, using php, displaying the every row's data of a mySQL table if a value in a particular column is met? Example:

**Table**

```
Name       Age         Gender       Color       Height
Frank      1           Boy          Red         5 foot 9
Mark       1           Boy          blue        4 foot 2
Susan      2           Girl         green       9 foot 17
```

I need an echo output of all with an 'age' of 1, such as-

```
Frank 1 Boy
Mark 1 Boy
```

Bonus points if each rows columns values can be output in a html !

Comment: Do you need help with PHP or SQL?

Comment: We can't teach you PHP and MySQL languages from scratch! Read [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/) and [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect(DB_Server,DB_User,User_Pass);
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_Name);
$age="1";
$sql="select * from table where age=".$age;

$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>


<table width="578" border="1" align="center" id="menu">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Name</th>

<th>age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
</tr>

<?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
?>

<tr>
 <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>

</tr></table>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look to using mysqli in PHP. Create the connection and query with your particular filters. The mysqli should then return a mysqli_result from your query and you should be able to retrieve the value and print it from there.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php